# why using sink function to save to a file returns empty file

Tags: r, sink

I tried to save screen text to a file by using the sink() function. The file was created but without any data inside it.What did I do wrong?
Here my toy code:

```
sink("sink3.txt")
df <- read.table(text = " color birds    wolfs     
                  red           9         7 
                 red           8         4 
                 red           2         8 
                 red           2         3 
                 black         8         3 
                 black         1         2 
                 black         7         16 
                 black         1         5 
                 black         17        7 
                 black         8         7 
                 black         2         7 
                 green         20        3 
                 green         6         3 
                 green         1         1 
                 green         3         11 
                 green         30         1  ",header = TRUE)
lm<-lm(birds ~ color + wolfs , data = df)
summary(lm)
sink()
```

Comment: Your code works for me (win10/R-3.2.3-x64 and linux/R-3.2.3-x64). Do you have the file open elsewhere, perhaps in an editor?

Comment: I restarted my computer and now it works.

Comment: Hello @r2evans, Do you know why the sink does not print to file errors? for example if I do an lm without the data=df  the sink function does not save the data / text to the file.

Comment: Read `help('sink')`, specifically the description of `type` options. As far as the restart goes, that's not uncommon with nested calls to `sink`, whether intentional or otherwise. Sometimes `showConnections()` can show you open connections indicating mid-execution sinks.